# What are the drawbacks of using BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost-asio

I have read the documentation and I understand that it is possible to use the `BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP` preprocessor definition to be able to call `cancel()` on a socket in Windows XP. The Boost library will then use a `select`-based solution instead and everything should work fine.

If this statements are true, what are the drawbacks of the `select`-based approach? Why we shouldn't always define `BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP`?

---

**EDIT 1**

I have compiled the DLL with `BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP` defined without problems. Unfortunately, after the integration with the final application, I'm getting memory access errors. Is there any additional configuration I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

IOCP should provide *much* better perfomance.

By the way, do you really have to use `cancel`? Note that after you cancel i/o operations on a socket, you have no idea what the actual state of you data flow is, so you'll need a sophisticated way to get synchronized with your peer. Thus, usually the right way to go is to `close` the socket.

> Unfortunately, after the integration with the final application, I'm
>   getting memmroy access errors.

Perhaps, you've got several modules that use Boost.Asio headers, but haven't defined BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP for *all* of them, causing ODR violation?

Comment: 1. I am waiting for messages from a device to broadcast them to the specific clients. I use `cancel` to perform a timed wait to receive. The other way to go could be closing and reopening the socket every time, but I am not sure on the impact of that way of operation.

Comment: 2. Boost headers are only used only in one module and the definition is included in the project definition. Does the value `BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP` has to be defined during the build of the Boost libraries?

Comment: @yeyeyerman, Well, I don't know oyur protocol against the device, but imagine it was sending the data when you cancelled i/o. Now, the device doesn't know if you've got the data or not, or got it partially - how would you resume the communication from this point? If you close the socket and open the session again, you re-initialize the session, and thus you get synchronized with the device.

Comment: @yeyeyerman, as far as I know, no other boost libs use asio, so it's unnecessary to define `BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP` for them. So, it's just an incorrect memory (or object lifetime) management. It often happens when dealing with async systems. Ensure that all your completion handlers outlive their async operations, use shared_from_this idiom.